# How to disallow a mongoDB user to update dataset?

Tags: mongodb, permissions

I've created an user `xyz` with "read" permissions an a given Databases:

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.xyz",
    "userId" : UUID("12345trntr4-3465465465771-4d6nre9-96rnc51-96rntrndfb33affebe"),
    "user" : "user01",
    "db" : "admin",
    "credentials" : {
        "SCRAM-SHA-1" : {
            "iterationCount" : 10000,
            "salt" : "08154711",
            "storedKey" : "raunuqfiagnuiraed132c4=",
            "serverKey" : "LH89uhiearnuiae323cj3k="
        },
        "SCRAM-SHA-256" : {
            "iterationCount" : 15000,
            "salt" : "nuqfgiaeh98hepQFGHdmnudtrianefqX1Ag==",
            "storedKey" : "nDuqfgiaeh98hepQFGHdmnudtrianefqmaM=",
            "serverKey" : "zNuqfgiaeh98hepQFGHdmnudtrianefqDI="
        }
    },
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "read",
            "db" : "myDatabase01"
        },
        {
            "role" : "read",
            "db" : "myDatabase02"
        }
    ]
}
```

And in fact, if I connect with a DB-Client, and try to enter `new Dataset` it is denied.

**BUT**, it is still possible to `EDIT` an existing entry.

### Question

How to I archive to have a user, who has read-only permission, but is not allowed to update (or change anything at all) in the Database?

Comment: Are you using access-control already present in Mongodb https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/, or is it a custom thing you are trying to implement?

Comment: Yep, I've tried to use this access-control you noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether `user1` has some *edit* role(s) in the DB itself (not in `admin` DB)?

e.g. by running

```js
   use myDatabase01;
   db.getUser("user1");

   use myDatabase02;
   db.getUser("user1");
```

A possible `readWrite` role defined on the specific DB (not in `admin` DB) might explain the weird situation that you are experiencing.